While doing the checkout I am receiving {} on checkout page of Razorpay
I am trying to implement a payment system in which while entering the amount we should be able to generate the qrcode. And when the user scans it, it should redirect to the checkout page. create order is working fine but when I scan the link it redirects to the page there it only return {}. Nothing checkout is returned.
try {
    // Create an order in Razorpay
    const order = await razorpay.orders.create({
      amount: amount * 100,
        currency: 'INR',
        receipt: `receipt_order_${Date.now()}`,
        payment_capture: 1,
    });

    // Generate a payment link
    const paymentLink = `https://rzp.io/i/${order.id}`;

    // Generate QR code URL
    const qrCodeData = await QRCode.toDataURL(paymentLink);

    // Save transaction to MongoDB
    const transaction = new Transaction({
        orderId: order.id,
        amount,
        currency: 'INR',
        status: 'created',
    });

    await transaction.save();

    res.json({
        success: true,
        qr_code_url: qrCodeData,
        order_id: order.id,
    });
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: error.message });
    }
});

I tried accessing the link through the browser or manually, it returns {} only.

May be your payment url contain incorrect required parameters. Here you are using orderId, make sure it included in QR code.
In this code snippets, this line of code might creating an issue. Make sure if it's not undefined
 // Generate a payment link
const paymentLink = `https://rzp.io/i/${order.id}`;

Please let me know, if you are still facing this issue

This is creating a bad request error

Its mean your getting error code 400
If yes, then go though its official docs
https://razorpay.com/docs/api/partners/errors/#400-bad-request-error

According to this screenshot from the documentation https://rzp.io/i/${order.id} is correct. Why have you changed it to https://rzp.io/i/?orderId=${order.id}&other=data? Maybe the bad request error is caused by your change?

Why do you expect the issue in that line? How would you solve it? Please clarify the question in the comments below the question before you post an answer, so that you don't have to guess in the answer. "May be" and "might" indicate bad answers.
